# why do I need network id and host id?

Tags: networking, network-programming

Here is what I think.

When I make request to some website, router through modem makes the request to the internet, (website) and gets the response. (how does it get response?) , webserver knows the router's ip address. Then router knows my private ip address and gives me back what I requested.

The question is , I heard that there's a subnet mask and I know what It does. Why do I need NETWORK ID at all? I read somewhere that it's used so that response could find the network from where request was done, but in above scenario, there's no network needed as web server knows router's ip address and gives it response.

**Why do I need(does router need) NetworkId and HostId to know specifically?**

Comment: There is no such thing as a network ID or host ID in TCP/IP. There are only IP addresses. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of confusion here. Your router does not need a network ID, and, in this context, I do not understand what you mean by a host ID.

> > When I make request to some website, router through modem makes the request to the internet, (website) and gets the response. (how does it get response?) , webserver knows the router's ip address. Then router knows my private ip address and gives me back what I requested.

Eh, no. That is not how it works. When your computer makes a request to a website your computer will first think about what to do with the request.

- Is the target directly connected? That means, if I AND the ip address with the netmask, is it the same as my own ip address ANDed with the netmask?
- Do I have a specific route for this ip address?
- otherwise, send it to the default gateway.

BTW: my own ip address ANDed with the netmask is my network. So a router may store  this if it does not want to perform the calculation every time.

Your router will forward the packet to the destination. It does not make a request to the Internet. In the case of a home-NAT-router, it will modify some fields in the protocol header, but it will not make a request of its own.